# Python and psycopg detect network error

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg

When connected to a postgresql database using psycopg and I pull the network cable I get no errors.   How can I detect this in code to notify the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

psycopg can't detect what happens with the network. For example, if you unplug your ethernet cable, replug it and execute a query everything will work OK. You should definitely get an exception when psycopg tries to send some SQL to the backend and there is no network connection but depending on the exact netwokr problem it can take some time. In the worst case you'll have to wait for a TCP timeout on the connection (several tens of seconds).

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely get an error the next time you try and execute a query, so I wouldn't worry if you can't alert the user at the exact instance they lose there network connection.

Comment: Except I am not getting any errors.  The code simply hangs on fetchall() and never raises an error.